# Get a list of exported components from javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, export, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, auto-import

Is there a (better) way to get the exported components from an installed library from node_modules, given the paths of the files? The only way I can think of is to parse the file, line by line, and look for them.

To give you the context, I am writing an eslint plugin to replace some imported components to a new library, with a new structure. I want, by giving the paths of the indexes (in node_modules folder), the plugin to be able to fetch the exported components and replace everything by itself. I believe this was done before but I can not find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Imports**

Why don't you change `imports` of your library instead? It looks like a hack to patch files in `node_modules`. If you need some other exports you can write a new library that will re-export only what you need. Also the idea you want to implement makes harder with constructions like this:

```js
export * from './api.js';
```

You need to walk all the exports in all files.

If you work with **CommonJS**, it can dynamically `export` things:

```js
buildSomeApiExports();

function buildSomeExports() {
    module.exports = {};
}
```

And this code is correct, and due to it's dynamic nature this is really hard task to do for statical analysis of **ESLint** plugin.

In case you will work with `imports` of your application, you can use [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer I'm working on, it can look [this way](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/d2e60d06e8510b27158516115654a3bc/4486b9e9d4d19fdf039702e68b6c31ec8ca7d54e):

```js
export const replace = () => ({
    'import {old} from "old-library"': 'import {newOne} from "new-library"',
});
```

This is [**Replacer**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#replacer) but you can get more sophisticated examples with [other plugin types](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#supported-plugin-types).

**Exports**

If you want to parse exports, here is [more sophisticated example](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/2ad3b9ad5303d10bdbebe0cb3911b51f/b12a24fd1001dab0c359b9ed46df6d90e36d228a).

The input:

```js
const start = '';
/*
*/

module.exports = () => {};
module.exports.readFile = () => {};

export const writeFile = () => {};
export default () => {};

export * from './abc.js';
```

Can be processed with [**Includer**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#includer):

```js
export const fix = (path) => {
    const {body} = path.scope.getProgramParent().path.node;
    const comment = body[0].trailingComments[0];
    
    if (path.isAssignmentExpression())
        comment.value += `    CommonJS: ${path.get('left.property')}\n`;
    
    if (path.isExportNamedDeclaration())
        comment.value += `    ESM: ${path.get('declaration.declarations.0.id')}\n`;
    
    if (path.isExportDefaultDeclaration())
        comment.value += `    ESM: default\n`;
    
    if (path.isExportAllDeclaration())
        comment.value += `    ESM: parse: ${path.node.source.value}\n`;
};

export const include = () => [
    'module.exports = __a',
    'module.exports.__a = __b',
    'export default __a',
    'export const __a = __b',
    'export * from "__"',
];
```

And here is result:

```js
const start = '';
/*
    CommonJS: exports
    CommonJS: readFile
    ESM: writeFile
    ESM: default
    ESM: parse: ./abc.js
*/

module.exports = () => {};
module.exports.readFile = () => {};

export const writeFile = () => {};
export default () => {};

export * from './abc.js';
```

You can run it with [`eslint-plugin-putout`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-putout), or using **Putout** [directly](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v27.13.0/packages/eslint-plugin-putout/lib/putout) in your ESLint plugin code

Comment: this is not helpful. I asked how can I get a list of the exported components names. I don't want to patch node modules, I was thinking of parsing it.

Comment: Well, in that case you can search for `export` in case of ESM, and `module.exports` in case of CommonJS. But you also need to  take a look at `package.json` to know what files are exported.

Comment: Just added exports example.